# Get category title with shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

i'd like to create a shortcode for wordpress to display the category name and i found this code :

```
function categories_list_func( $atts ){
 $categories = get_the_category();

     if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= '<li class="cat-' . $category->cat_ID . '"><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "Read more posts from : %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></li>';
        }
        $second_output = trim($output);
      }
      $return_string = '<h4>'.__( "Categories :", "my_site").'</h4><div class="overflow"><ul class="post-categories">' . $second_output . '</ul></div>';

 return $return_string;

} // END Categories
add_shortcode( 'categories-list', 'categories_list_func' );
```

But i know nothing in PHP and i'd like to remove everything (the link and "Catégorie :" in h4) except the category name.
I managed to do this with CSS but i'd like a clean php code if possible.

Could you help me please ?
Thanks.
Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code you want with link to categories :

```
<?php  
function categories_list_func( $atts ){
 $categories = get_the_category();

     if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= '<li class="cat-' . $category->cat_ID . '"><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "Read more posts from : %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></li>';
        }
        $second_output = trim($output);
      }
      $return_string = '<ul>' . $second_output . '</ul>';

 return $return_string;

} // END Categories
add_shortcode( 'categories-list', 'categories_list_func' );

?>
```

and this is only the names without any listing and any links

```
function categories_list_func( $atts ){
 $categories = get_the_category();

     if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= '<li>'.$category->cat_name.'</li>';
        }
        $second_output = trim($output);
      }
      $return_string = '<ul>' . $second_output . '</ul>';

 return $return_string;

} // END Categories
add_shortcode( 'categories-list', 'categories_list_func' );
```

or if you want it in another way dont hesitate to tell me :)

Comment: Hello, 
It's perfect ! Thanks a lot !